# I need to verify breaker size

Tags: circuit-breaker, kitchens

I'm installing an older glasstop stovetop range.
GE model #JP960W0A1WW
I'm replacing old full stove unit w/ a 50 Amp breaker.
So w/ this glass top, do I need a 40 or 50 Amp breaker?
Thankx for your time
Paul

Comment: Need to find what the stovetop requires  Seems that stovetop requires 50 amps at 240 volts.

Answer (score 3):

According to the specifications, this cooktop is rated for 50A at 240V but actually uses 9.6 kW at 240V, which is 40A. That all makes sense based on the standard continuous use derate - 50A breaker *and wire*, 40A actual usage.

The issue is *not* so much the breaker. Replacing breakers is easy and inexpensive. It is the wire. You need one of:

- 6 AWG (or larger) copper NM cable
- 8 AWG (or larger) copper wires in conduit
- 6 AWG (or larger) aluminum wires in conduit, provided the breaker (normal) and receptacle or cooktop connection can properly handle aluminum and local code permits it

If you already have a 50A breaker *and appropriate cable or wires* then you don't have to change anything. But it is worth double-checking the cable or wires as it is quite possible that there was a 40A breaker at one time and upgraded improperly.